# "Name1 Name2 are also want to join?"

Tags: american-english, non-native-english

"name1 name2 are also want to join?" Is totally incorrect, however, I am unable to explain it, so as why is it incorrect. Could you please help me explain it?

Comment: This is confusing because the words "are + want" has a different meaning than "want" or "welcome". Please clarify and provide any information you've gained from research. Thanks.

Comment: `He wants to join`, `They want to join`, `He also wants to join`, `They also want to join` - The verb `to be` is not used with `want` - more here http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/verbtobe.html

Comment: Because you cannot have two conjugated verbs in one phrase like this. The sentence is wrong because it violates basic grammar concerning the use and conjugation of English verbs. Apart from that something is missing between name1 _and_ name2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage "name1 name2" in "....are also want to join ? " is incorrect.It should be "name1 and name2" like Jim pointed out

> unless if it is denoting the first and last names of a syndicate/group.

So here we go,

> "Jim and Tom are also wanting to join?"
>
> "Jim and Tom want to join ?"
>
> "The Famous Five are also wanting to join ?"
>
> "The Famous Five want to join?"

Answer (score 2):

"name1 and name2 also want to join?" would be right. No need to say 'are'.

Also,

"name1 and name2 are also wanting to join?" would be right.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So for example *Jim Tom also want to join* is correct??

Comment: `Jim and Tom also want...`